# how to check system configuration of modules in admin magento2

Tags: magento2

I have installed magento2 with sample data and also installed an "HelloWorld" extension of Amasty.

But I didn't find any link to check module's configuration as we can see in Magento 1.x as - System->Configuration .

But I didn't find any "Configuration" link under "System" tab. 
Please let me know how to check this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find configuration under the stores tab now.

Answer (score 0):

Better do

`php bin/magento module:status`